# In React Native, how do I get these arrows to appear properly on an ImageBackground?

Tags: css, ios, react-native

I am trying to have an ImageBackground with button arrows laid on top at the cardinal directions. The way I'm thinking about this is that there is an `<ImageBackground />` with `flexDirection = 'column'` and `justifyContent = 'space-between'`, along with three items within it:

1. An Up arrow at the top.
2. A left and right arrow in the middle.
3. A down arrow at the bottom.

The left and right arrow row is a flex row with `justifyContent = 'space-between'`.

However, this is not working (image attached). What am I doing wrong?

```
    const rightButton = (
        <View style={styles.horizontalButtonContainer}>
            <Icon
            name="arrow-right"
            backgroundColor="#3b5998"
            onPress={pressRight}
            style={styles.horizontalButton}
            />          
        </View>
    );

    const leftButton = (
        <View style={styles.horizontalButtonContainer}>
            <Icon
            name="arrow-left"
            backgroundColor="#3b5998"
            onPress={pressLeft}
            style={styles.horizontalButton}
            />          
        </View>
    );

    const downButton = (
        <View style={styles.verticalButtonContainer}>
            <Icon
                name="arrow-down"
                backgroundColor="#3b5998"
                onPress={pressDown}
                style={styles.verticalButton}
            />          
        </View>
    );

    const upButton = (
        <View style={styles.verticalButtonContainer}>
            <Icon
                name="arrow-up"
                onPress={pressUp}
                style={styles.verticalButton}
            />          
        </View>
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <ImageBackground resizeMode={'cover'} style={styles.imageBackground} source={{uri: imageUrl}}>
                <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                    {upButton}
                    <View style={styles.innerButtonsContainer}>
                        {leftButton}
                        {rightButton}
                    </View>
                    {downButton}
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    verticalButton: {
        width: 75,
        height: 75
    },
    verticalButtonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    horizontalButton: {
        width: 75,
        height: 75
    },
    horizontalButtonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },    
    buttonsContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    innerButtonsContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    imageContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    imageBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'        
    },
})

[![Image of current setup][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmZMW.jpg
```

Comment: Which code is not display?

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
buttonsContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
innerButtonsContainer: {
  flexDirection: "row",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
verticalButton: {
  alignSelf: "center"
}
```